# Passing File Attachment with PHP Post

Tags: php, file-upload, podio

We currently have a site that provides webforms. (podio.com)

These webforms are limited, as it does not provide conditional formatting.
(ex. Selecting option A, unhides field 1,2,4 to fill out or 
Selecting option B, unhides field 1,4,6 to fill out.)

My solution: I created a php webform, with the same fields, and im able to control conditionals this way. I then just POST the variables to the other site/webform and it submits the form.
Works Great!

Now the issue is attachments.

So my question is: How would i go about pushing an attachment from my new form to the other form so it actual is submitted?

My current code for the attachment:
`<input type="file" name="attachments[]" value="" accept="" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0:$0.0">`

This obviously lets them chose a file, but how would i go about carrying this attachment to the actual webforms 'choose file upload' field, so it submits with the other data?

Please let me know if i need to explain more.

Comment: Do you have enctype="multipart/form-data on the form? This should just post the data (assuming the form input has the same name)

Comment: All this is far too complicated.

Create a form with all the fields, including your selector. For a nicer interface, hide or show the fields according to your selector.

the php script that receives the data in post contains your fields + the image + your selector. The logic of the script handles the fields according to the value of the selector.

Comment: @Eric I guess im not understanding your solution. :/ here is the original webform. 
https://podio.com/webforms/23288110/1664792
and then here is the one ive created : http://adcommpodio.com/infotech/webforms/tickets/

If its too much to explain I understand. I have everything working except the files. My thought was maybe i would have to somehow upload it to a temp folder and then push it to the form on submission. Like i said im not as advanced in this as some. ty for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this  : you can't use a local image in your second form, because the file is not stored on the user computer.  
 but  when you receive the first form : encode the image in base64 and use it in second generated form
1) use  <img src = "data:image/png;base64, xxxxxx" .  to display image
2) use  a hidden field with value="xxxxxx..."  to send to 2nd script


note : the picture cannot be changed.

you can add a option (input check box) "choose another file" to allow picking another local file, then the script check if it should handle the first picture
(base 64 encoded) or the new picture, according the "choose another file" check box value

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="/infotech/webforms/tickets/results.php" 
 method="post" name="it_webform">
```

to this

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="/infotech/webforms/tickets/results.php" 
method="post" name="it_webform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

as Clint pointed out, this needs to be there. This is infact required on ANY form that is expected to send files, without this enctype attribute, the form is just basic text for all the server cares and the files array is not sent.